# Resizing a partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[image]I recently bought a Lenovo X1 Carbon with Ubuntu pre-installed. I accidentally was in "disks" and deleted the 4.5GB recovery partition. I cotacted Lenovo and they told me once deleted the recovery partition cannot be restored?

This does not really bother me, as I have no plans to go back to the factory settings ever, and if I need a re-install I can always start fresh.

But what is bothering me, is I have 4.5GB of un-allocated space (see attached image). I have tried in Ubuntu Disks and G parted GUI, to resize my main SSD and use up this now unused 4.5GB of space, but when i try to resize it does not show that I have free space, and I cannot make the main SSD any bigger.

Does anyone know how I can use up this 4.5Gb? as it just sitting there un-allocated is driving me nuts

Comment: Hello. A search of this site will give you many many same questions with answers. I will tell you you have to boot from live media and use gparted. You can not work on an in use disk.

Comment: well ... if the purpose of the 4.5 GB is irrelevant, one option would be to format it as a swap partition and add it to your existing swap file. This would give you a little more flexibility when working with memory-intensive (or file-read-heavy) applications ... 

Comment: Perfect, I will just use it as a swap, Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using Gparted GUI. Allocating that 4.5GB partition as linux swap, check green tick.

Right click and turn swapon.

Done, an extra 4GB swap